# displaying album art for music using picasso

Tags: android, uri, picasso, android-file

Hello I need to display **album art** for music files efficiently using **Picasso**. I already configured picasso in my app. But I am not able to display album art from internal storage for music files.

I tried this code but it's not working means no error but it doesn't display anything.

1. Using uri :

   ```
   cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DURATION + ">0", null, sortOrder);

   cursor.moveToFirst();

   a = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID));

   l = Long.parseLong(a);
   final Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
   Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, l);

   Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(uri).into(iv);
   ```
2. Using new File :

   ```
   cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DURATION + ">0", null, sortOrder);

   cursor.moveToFirst();

   a = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID));

   Picasso.with(this)
          .load(Uri.parse("file://"+a))
          .error(R.drawable.color_music_player_logo)
          .into(iv);
   ```

Comment: give us your log

Comment: There is no any error it just don't display anything.

Comment: if you added permission to you manifest and i think you did that. maybe there is nothing to show! try with putting a picture in your resource. `int resourceId = R.mipmap.ic_launcher.`
`Picasso  
    .with(context)
    .load(resourceId)
    .into(imageViewResource);`

Comment: This is correct but I want to get image from sd card or internal storage not from resource.

Comment: my guess is the address or query you are trying to load an image from doesn't have what you want

Comment: So is there any other solution or library to solve this type of problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137514/discussion-between-mehran-zamani-and-pedo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give Picasso absolute path to your image like this:

```
String name = "image.jpeg";
String dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
Picasso.with(context).load(new File(dir + File.separator + name)).into(iv);
```

or you can use `filechooser` so you can select which image to load or show list of images and onclick loads an image for you ....

Comment: I will back to you after my class and thanks for help

Comment: Okay okay I will get back to you