# display album art using picasso (f4om storage)

Tags: android, picasso

I am creating music player app.

I need to display album art efficiently so I used picasso. In that I able to display images using url.

This is okay but when I try to display it from internal storage simply it is not displayed and it gives no error.

What Iyou can see in my another account

[displaying album art for music using picasso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42623276/displaying-album-art-for-music-using-picasso)

I posted this again because I don't get any answer. You can give answer in any account.

Comment: give us your log

Comment: Thanks for response.

Comment: Actually there is no any error and what i tried is inside link given

Comment: are you sure that your cursor has any image in it?